# A question regarding the matrix matrix $P^{-1}DP$ where $D=diag(1,0,\ldots,0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix which is similar to $D=diag(1,0,\ldots,0)$ and Let $P$ be the invertible matrix such that $P^{-1}AP=D$. What is the vector
$$
A
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\1\\ \vdots \\1
\end{pmatrix}=?
$$
**My attempt**: If the matrix is $2\times2$ and
$$
P=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ c & d\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where
$$
\vec{v}=
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ c \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is the eigenvector of $1$, then we get
$$
A
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\1\\
\end{pmatrix}=
P
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\1\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{d-b}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}
a\\c\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How to generalized it to any order $n$?

Comment: Without knowing what motivates this problem, it seems to me not a lot can be said about the answer in terms of $P$ and $A$ beyond the fairly routine rewriting.  If it's important, I can spell out the details in an Answer.  You've hit on the crux of the problem with your remark about "the eigenvector of $1$".

Comment: Thanks @hardmath. I will be happy to a detailed answer.

Comment: I'd already written an Answer, but would be happy to learn of your intended application.

Comment: Why do you need to diagonalize $A$? Direct multiplication is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P^{-1} A P = D = \operatorname{diag}(1,0,\ldots,0)$, then:

$$ A = P D P^{-1}$$

Note that the title presents this relationship differently than the body of your Question, but let's go with the latter.  Also let's assume the matrix $A$ is meant to have real number entries.

Thus:

$$ A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = P D  P^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Without more information, not much more can be said about this vector.  Indeed without further restrictions $A$ can be any rank $1$ matrix with trace $1$, i.e.

$$ A = u v^T $$

for some nonzero (column) vectors $u,v$ such that trace $A = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i = 1$.  Without loss of generality one can scale the vector $v$ to have entries that sum to $1$, by correspondingly multiplying the vector $u$ by the reciprocal of the sum of entries in $v$.

Now $v^T (1,1,\ldots,1)^T = r$, the sum of entries in $v$.  It follows that:

$$ A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = r u $$

We can arrange for this vector to be any $u$ with Euclidean norm $1$, i.e. sum of entries squared is one, and scalar $r$ the sum of entries of $v$.  Perhaps that is the conclusion you were meant to draw.

---

The symmetric case is particularly easy to understand.  Let $u$ be any (column) vector in $\mathbb R^n$ with Euclidean norm $1$.

Then $A = uu^T$ is a symmetric rank one matrix with trace $1$.  Note that its diagonalized form is $D$ as described in this Question.

Now $A (1,1,\ldots,1)^T = u u^T (1,1,\ldots,1)^T = r u$ where scalar $r = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i$.